# Logging in as ParseUser works after second click on log in button

Tags: android, authentication, parse-platform

I want to log in as a ParseUser. Everything works but after second click on button `Log in`.

```
private void openMainActivity(boolean loggedIn) {
    if (loggedIn){
        startActivity(new Intent(ParseStarterProjectActivity.this, MainPage.class));
        finish();
    }else{
        initialize();
        logInBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (logIn(username.getText().toString(),pwd.getText().toString())){
                    startActivity(new Intent(ParseStarterProjectActivity.this, MainPage.class));
                    finish();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Failed to log in, try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Log in method:**

```
private boolean logIn(String username, String pwd) {
    ParseUser.logInInBackground(username, pwd, new LogInCallback() {
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
            if (user != null) {
                loggedIn=true;
             } else {
                loggedIn=false;
            }
        }
    });
    return loggedIn;
}
```

Is it an issue of time? That it doesn't get values from `EditText` immediately, maybe callback delay? Or any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `ParseUser.logInInBackground()` is an async call.

You're telling it to start the log-in process, it will finish some time later after the code talks to the Parse server and gets a response.

You're then trying to use the value of `loggedIn` before that value has been set.

With async code you get to tell it what to do later when the code finishes (that `public void done()` block). Your `startActivity()` etc code should be inside the callback block.